# Is there any way to display the FAB button correctly?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

You know why the studio makes the fab button look like this? 
One day I've taken all my time
Works in other projects or projects alright, does not work here. 
See the program and output image

[image: HERE]

=>> The problem is that it's not working on the same project!

Comment: Do you see the fab button also in runtime like this?

Comment: did you added design support dependency in build.gradle file ?? Also,add proper constraints to your layout and refer a good tutorial for fab.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this or you can use [Materials](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/)

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_my_icon"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I've done these methods, it did not work!